# LINK columns to rows in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL database in which I created 2 tables.

- One of these has a "ID" column with several entries in it (for this example, lets say [0, 1, 2, 3]).
- The second table needs to have the same number of entries, but as columns. So each "ID" row in the first table corresponds to a column in this second table.

My question is:

#### How do I setup the second table to update its columns according to "ID" rows in the first table?

I would rather use **PHPMyAdmin** to setup these tables since I'm not creating it in any code. But I don't know any solution for it either way...

*Edit*: Basically, each entry value in the "ID" column will be the name of the corresponding column in the second table.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like below everytime you add a row to `Table 1` to create a column in `Table 2`:

```
$table2  = 'your table name';
$column = 'q1'
$add = mysql_query("ALTER TABLE $table2 ADD $column VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL");
```